# civicrm_processProfile hook ignored

Tags: developer, hooks

After submitting the profile with success from the front-end of the site, a civicrm contact is created but the following hook is not working..

```
function wordpress_civicrm_processProfile($name) {
        if ($name === 'supporter_profile_91') {
                die('we are here');
                //also tried error_log(); nothing!
        }
}
```

Its written in `wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom-PHP/civicrmHooks.php` and other civihooks/wp functions in that file are firing correctly.

Profile set from `Manage Contribution Pages > [Specific Contribution Page] > Personal Campaigns [tab] > Supporter Profile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this hook is not called when a profile form is submitted on the front-end of the site. The hook is fired during the creation/edit of a profile. Found through a Google search

```
Page Title: hook_civicrm_processProfile - CiviCRM 4.3 Documentation ARCHIVE ...
Page Link: wiki.civicrm.org:8090/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=86638695
```

Dropped the port 8090 in the SERP link to see the wiki page that says:

> This hook is invoked when processing a submitted CiviCRM profile form (e.g. for "civicrm/profile/create" or "civicrm/profile/edit"). This hook may be used to inject additional markup, scripts, or styles on the profile.

I dont know why that important detail was dropped among other important details. The most recent wiki has no such text.

Edit: added as issue in 2017devdocs.